# Implicit conversion between int and varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, implicit-conversion

Below query show conversion error.

```
select 'a'
union all
select 1
```

to execute I have to explicitly convert it..

Is there any other way for implicit conversion?

Comment: Put `select '1'`

Comment: I want to run the same query.. I want to know is there any setting like collation to do the task

Answer (score 0):

**may be we can convert integer to varchar explicitily.But in implicit we can convert alphabets to convert using ASCII values**

```
select ASCII('a')
union all
select 1
```

or

```
select 'a'
union all
select CAST(1 AS VARCHAR)
```